# Finding the sum of dates using first column value

Tags: excel

So I am working in excel and have two columns, as shown below.

[image]

What I wish to do is to able to get the sum of yearly deadlines for A, B and C.

So that:

- Get a sum of dates within Year 2020 for each Variable
- Get a sum of dates within Month/Year for each specific A,B and C.

Currently, I have been using a long approach. I use a Vlookup for each row getting a filtered table for each Variable. Then using that I filter out Dates using combination of Countif and Countifs. But the problem with that approach is that I end up getting huge rows and table of data in the end increasing the file size.

I have also tried to use sumproduct() but I do not have numbers so I can not find a sum.

Is there a smart way of doing it using one formula?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT`. For year/variable:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$13=E2)*(YEAR($B$2:$B$13)=$F$1))
```

for month/year/variable:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$13=$E2)*(YEAR($B$2:$B$13)=$F$1)*(MONTH($B$2:$B$13)=G$1))
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to go into three levels as well with this approach? Let us say I have a third column as as well, and I want to perform the same just with a third variable? Is that possible?

Comment: @MathCurious314 Of course, you can add as many columns as you want.